# How to convert markdown img to vue component in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, markdown, vuejs3, markdown-it

When converting `markdown` string to `HTML` content, `img` will be convert to an actual `<img>` tag.

What I want is allow user to `click` on that image, then pop out a modal, where user can visit a bigger size of iamge.

If `<img>` tag can be replaced by a custom Vue component, then everything will be simpler.
But how can I do that?

Comment: Most markdown parsers permit extensions, or you could post-process the markdown HTML to add events to all image tags.

Answer (score 0):

[VuePress 2](https://vuepress2.netlify.app/) and [VitePress](https://vitepress.vuejs.org/) both allow you to use Vue 3 components directly in Markdown files.

*Example markdown with Vue SFC:*

```markdown
[Home](../README.md)
[About](../about/README.md)

_Hello world_

<img @click="showModal = true" :src="imgUrl">
<MyModal v-if="showModal" />

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import MyModal from '@/components/MyModal.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    MyModal
  },
  setup() {
    return {
      showModal: ref(false),
      imgUrl: 'path/to/image'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```